# How to remove non-numeric lines from multi-text files?

Tags: bash

I have some text files with strange characters.

They look like this,

[image: Screenshot]

How could I remove the lines with strange codes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to allow the following characters: `0-9,.-/` and a space.

Do a `grep` that looks for things that are NOT that, and print everything else `-v`:

```
grep -v '[^0-9,./ ]' file.txt
```